# Powershell scripting: switching contexts between hybrid Exchange on-prem and online

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation, exchange-server, hybrid

Environment is hybrid Exchange with AD sync and ADFS/SSO.

I have a new user onboarding script that I'm writing that needs to perform commands against our on-prem server to create AD account and enable remote mailbox. It triggers an ADsync, waits 5 minutes, then connects to MSOLservice to provision a licence.

The next step is to set shared mailbox permissions, but when I run get-mailbox it's pulling on-prem mailboxes instead of remote ones.

I've tried unloading the EMS snap-in and AD module, and closing my sessions. As soon as I load get-mailbox it creates a session back to on prem.

Can't pipe get-remotemailbox into get-mailboxpermissions. 
Can't use invoke-command to run `get-mailbox |get-mailboxpermission | where-object {$_.user -eq "user@domain.com"}` (See [no-language error here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2014/03/04/powershell-automation-from-net/) for why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to use prefixes:

http://www.stevieg.org/2010/11/managing-office-365-on-premises-exchange-2010-powershell-session/

```
Import-PSSession $o365Session -prefix cloud
get-cloudmailbox |get-cloudmailboxpermission ...
```